# Adding to a list when there is a match only

Tags: list, filenames, equality

The following function replaces filenames and places the result in a list.  Although the list gets filled, I do not want to add the filename when there is no match.  How can I avoid sending non-matching situations from being added to the list?

```
(defvar my-list-for-later-access '())

(defun mash-homedir (username)
  "Substitute USERNAME into the pathname at point."
  (interactive "MUsername: ")
  (add-to-list
   'my-list-for-later-access
   (s-replace-regexp
    "/home/[^/]+/"
    (format "/home/%s/" username)
    (thing-at-point 'filename :no-properties))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `file-exists-p` is the function you want.

See also `C-h i g (elisp)Testing Accessibility`

---

> Not checking if file exists but if there is a match to `"/home/[^/]+/"`.

I'd do something like this, then:

```el
(when-let* ((filename (thing-at-point 'filename :no-properties))
            (index (string-match "^/home/[^/]+/\\(.+\\)" filename)))
  (add-to-list 'my-list-for-later-access
               (format "/home/%s/%s" username (match-string 1 filename))))
```

Comment: Not checking if file exists but if there is a match to `"/home/[^/]+/"`.

Comment: Answer updated.